# How to add image upload property in model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a simple movie database, and I'm trying to insert an image property as in this picture:

[image: View movies]

How can I create something similar to this, using the properties I have:

```
public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

So when I want to create new movie I'll have an option to upload an image.

[image: Create movie]

Comment: Bitmap or Byte[] datatype.  Just create another property on your Movie class.

Comment: Do you wish to store the images in the database or are they to be referenced directly from a webserver?

Comment: yes i would like to add them in db with the other properties so i can get like on this picture to browse for images; 

https://acomdpsstorage.blob.core.windows.net/dpsmedia-prod/azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-get-started/20150406051838/create.png

Comment: Have a look at this mvc / ajax tutorial http://davidsonsousa.net/en/post/how-to-upload-a-file-using-mvc-3-and-ajax

Comment: Or this is a fuller tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806075/File-Upload-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASP-NET-Web-API

Answer (score 0):

**Update your Model to store the image**

```
public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        //New Property to Store Image
        public byte[] Image { get;set;}

        //Feel free to move this out of your entities
        [NotMapped]
        public HttpPostedFileBase Content { get;set;}

        public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**Add an Action to save the Movie**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Add(Movie model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(model.Content.InputStream))
        {
            movie.Image = reader.ReadBytes(model.Content.ContentLength);
        }
           //Plug in your db context
           db.Movies.Add(movie);
           await db.SaveChangesAsync();

           return redirectToAction("Index");
    }

    Return View();
}
```

Feel free to add validation to check the files contentType & length.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but Im getting some errors

The type or namespace name 'ReadBytes' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader'

Comment: Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.BinaryReader.BinaryReader(System.IO.Stream)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @john Apologies I had the binary reader and readbyte parameters the wrong way round.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.

First of all you add a string property in your model. In this way you will save only the image path (assuming that you will upload the images into a folder).

Then you add an upload control into your page to upload the images.

I wrote about this here a while ago: http://davidsonsousa.net/en/post/how-to-upload-a-file-using-mvc-3-and-ajax (there is an example for download in the end)

In case you can't save the images in a folder due some technical limitations you can save them in the database as heymega pointed earlier.

Comment: The thing is that im pretty much new to asp.net mvc almost 2 months, so this is just a bit too hard for me now ;(,  so much stuff just to insert an image, so is there some more beginners-friendly tutorial about this that can help me?